# Take n number of rows after value for each column

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, lag

I have a data frame dt

```
         V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
52  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
53  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
54 23.41610 27.74736  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
55 46.25229 26.80305 12.08680  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
56 16.93179  0.00000 12.76963 12.21179  0.00000  0.00000
57  0.00000 24.35663  0.00000 15.47197 11.55125  0.00000
58 46.11487 14.91367  0.00000  0.00000 16.51914 12.40029
59 35.93963  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 15.10201 13.44208
60  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
```

For each column, I want to find the first value greater than 1 and select the `(n-1:n+25)` rows around it, and put them into a new data table.

I've tried using data.table with

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {df[i >1 | shift(i>1, n=1L, type = "lead") | shift(i>1, n=25L, type = "lag")]}
```

but I am apparently calling my columns wrong.

I've tried using `seq_along` as well in the same for loop structure just to get the 25 "after" rows:

```
output <- seq(min(which(df[i] > 1)), length.out = 25)
```

Which gave me the series of row numbers for the first column only where the threshold was met.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: is `dt` a `data.table` or `data.frame`?

Comment: Also are you guaranteed to find the value before `nrow(dt)-25`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample table, do you want something like this? For demonstration purpose I only used `target_row + 2` instead of `+ 25`.

As suggested in the comment, replacing `min(which(df[, x] > 1))` with `which(df[, x] > 1)[1L]` or `which.max(df[, x] > 1)` might be more efficient.

```r
sapply(1:ncol(df), \(x) {
  target_row <- min(which(df[, x] > 1))
  df[(target_row - 1):(target_row + 2), x]
  })

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
[1,]  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
[2,] 23.41610 27.74736 12.08680 12.21179 11.55125 12.40029
[3,] 46.25229 26.80305 12.76963 15.47197 16.51914 13.44208
[4,] 16.93179  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 15.10201  0.00000
```

#### Input

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 23.4161, 46.25229, 16.93179, 0, 46.11487, 
35.93963, 0), V2 = c(0, 0, 27.74736, 26.80305, 0, 24.35663, 14.91367, 
0, 0), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 12.0868, 12.76963, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 12.21179, 15.47197, 0, 0, 0), V5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
11.55125, 16.51914, 15.10201, 0), V6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.40029, 
13.44208, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"))
```

Comment: `which(df[, x] > 1)[1L]` would do less work than `min(which(df[, x] > 1))`

Comment: `which.max(df[, x] > 1)` would do even less.

Answer (score 1):

Using *data.table* (essentially the same as benson's):

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(i){ 
  x <- min(which(i > 1))
  i[ (x - 1):(x + 2) ]
  })]

#          V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
# 1:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
# 2: 23.41610 27.74736 12.08680 12.21179 11.55125 12.40029
# 3: 46.25229 26.80305 12.76963 15.47197 16.51914 13.44208
# 4: 16.93179  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 15.10201  0.00000
```

Comment: first() would do less work than min() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

*If* there are many rows and the row we are looking for is generally found early on, a loop would be more efficient than comparing the whole vector:

```
find_first <- function(x) {
  i <- 1L
  n <- length(x)
  while (x[i] <= 1 && i <= n) i <- i + 1L
  i
}    
dt[, lapply(.SD, \(x) x[find_first(x) + (-1:2)])]
#          V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
#       <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>
# 1:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
# 2: 23.41610 27.74736 12.08680 12.21179 11.55125 12.40029
# 3: 46.25229 26.80305 12.76963 15.47197 16.51914 13.44208
# 4: 16.93179  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 15.10201  0.00000
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  V1 = c(0, 0, 23.4161, 46.25229, 16.93179, 0, 46.11487, 35.93963, 0),
  V2 = c(0, 0, 27.74736, 26.80305, 0, 24.35663, 14.91367, 0, 0),
  V3 = rep(c(0, 12.0868, 12.76963, 0), c(3L, 1L, 1L, 4L)),
  V4 = rep(c(0, 12.21179, 15.47197, 0), c(4L, 1L, 1L, 3L)),
  V5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.55125, 16.51914, 15.10201, 0),
  V6 = rep(c(0, 12.40029, 13.44208, 0), c(6L, 1L, 1L, 1L))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, assuming `data.table`:

```r
df[, lapply(.SD, function(z) z[fcoalesce(cumsum(z > 1 | shift(z, type="lead") > 1) > 0, TRUE)][1:5])]
#          V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
#       <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>
# 1:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
# 2: 23.41610 27.74736 12.08680 12.21179 11.55125 12.40029
# 3: 46.25229 26.80305 12.76963 15.47197 16.51914 13.44208
# 4: 16.93179  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 15.10201  0.00000
# 5:  0.00000 24.35663  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000       NA
```

- `z > 0 | shift(z, type="lead") > 0` in the perhaps-unlikely case that row 1 has a value over 1; if you *know* that the first number will never match, then you can remove `z > 0 |` from the expression
- `cumsum(..) > 0` is akin to `dplyr::cumany`
- `fcoalesce` because `shift(z, type="lead")` is `NA`, which incorrectly converts the last `0` to `NA` in `V5` and `V6`
- `.[1:5]` guarantees that we'll get length 5, filling the trailing elements with `NA` (as in `V6`); in contrast, `head(., 5)` can return shorter than 5, causing `data.table` to complain with *"has 4 rows but longest item has 5; recycled with remainder"*, which is then recycled (filled with 0)

Data

```r
df <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 23.4161, 46.25229, 16.93179, 0, 46.11487, 35.93963, 0), V2 = c(0, 0, 27.74736, 26.80305, 0, 24.35663, 14.91367, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 12.0868, 12.76963, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12.21179, 15.47197, 0, 0, 0), V5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.55125, 16.51914, 15.10201, 0), V6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.40029, 13.44208, 0)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L)))
```